# Lookup when foreignField is in an Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to lookup from an object to a collection where the `foreignField` key is embedded into an array of objects. I have:

collection "shirts"

```
{ 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a797ef0768d8418866eb0f6"), 
      "name" : "Supermanshirt", 
      "price" : 9.99,
      "flavours" : [
                     {
                       "flavId" : ObjectId("5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3"), 
                       "size" : "M", 
                       "color": "white",
                     },
                     {
                       "flavId" : ObjectId("3a797f8c768d8418866eb0f7"), 
                       "size" : "XL", 
                       "color": "red",
                     }, 
                   ]
}
```

collection "basket"

```
 { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc"), 
      "basketName" : "Default", 
      "items" : [
                   {
                      "dateAdded" : 1526996879787.0, 
                      "itemFlavId" : ObjectId("5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3")
                   }
                ], 
}
```

My Query:

```
basketSchema.aggregate([
                    {
                       $match: { $and: [{ _id }, { basketName }]},
                    },
                    {
                       $unwind: '$items',
                    },
                    {
                       $lookup:
                       {
                         from: 'shirts',
                         localField: 'items.itemFlavId',
                         foreignField: 'flavours.flavId',
                         as: 'ordered_shirts',
                       },
                    },
                    ]).toArray();
```

my expected result:

```
[{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc"), 
  "basketName" : "Default", 
  "items" : [
               {
                  "dateAdded" : 1526996879787.0, 
                  "itemFlavId" : ObjectId("5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3")
               }
            ], 
   "ordered_shirts" : [
                     { 
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5a797ef0768d8418866eb0f6"), 
                        "name" : "Supermanshirt", 
                        "price" : 9.99,
                        "flavours" : [
                                {
                                   "flavId" : ObjectId("5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3"), 
                                   "size" : "M", 
                                   "color": "white",
                                }
                   ]
}
            ], 
}]
```

but instead my ordered_shirts array is empty.

How can I use a `foreignField` if this `foreignField` is embedded in an array at the other collection?

I am using MongoDB 3.6.4

Comment: Works for me. I suggest that `"shirts"` may not be the collection name. Since you are using mongoose you can do, `Model.collection.name` where `Model` is the actual model instance you are using for "shirts" and that will point to it's collection name. But if you put those documents into collections you know the names of and run the query, then you get the expected result. You would be better filtering this down with the "non-correlated" form of `$lookup` anyway, since you still need to match your shirt from within the array. And the `$unwind` is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, it would appear that there is simply something up in your code where you are pointing at the wrong collection. The general case for this is to simply look at the example listing provided below and see what the differences are, since with the data you provide and the correct collection names then your expected result is in fact returned.

Of course where you need to take such a query "after" that initial [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage is not a simple matter. From a structural standpoint, what you have is generally not a great idea since referring "joins" into items within an array means you are always returning data which is not necessarily "related".

There are some ways to combat that, and mostly there is the form of "non-correlated" [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) introduced with MongoDB 3.6 which can aid in ensuring you are not returning "unnecessary" data in the "join".

I'm working here in the form of "merging" the *"sku"* detail with the `"items"` in the basket, so a first form would be:

#### Optimal MongoDB 3.6

```
// Store some vars like you have
let _id = ObjectId("5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc"),
    basketName = "Default";

// Run non-correlated $lookup
let optimal = await Basket.aggregate([
  { "$match": { _id, basketName } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Shirt.collection.name,
    "as": "items",
    "let": { "items": "$items" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$setIsSubset": ["$$items.itemflavId", "$flavours.flavId"]
        }
      }},
      { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "items": {
          "$map": {
            "input": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$flavours",
                "cond": { "$in": [ "$$this.flavId", "$$items.itemFlavId" ]}
              }
            },
            "in": {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                { "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$$items",
                  { "$indexOfArray": [
                    "$$items.itemFlavId", "$$this.flavId" ] }
                ]},
                { "name": "$name", "price": "$price" },
                "$$this"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$items" },
      { "$replaceRoot": {  "newRoot": "$items" } }
    ]
  }}
])
```

Note that since you are using mongoose to hold details for the models we can use `Shirt.collection.name` here to read the property from that model with the actual collection name as needed for the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). This helps avoid confusion within the code and also "hard-coding" something like the collection name when it's actually stored somewhere else. In this way should you change the code which registers the "model" in a way which altered the collection name, then this would always retrieve the correct name for use in the pipeline stage.

The main reason you use this form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with MongoDB 3.6 is because you want to use that "sub-pipeline" to manipulate the foreign collection results "before" they are returned and merged with the parent document. Since we are "merging" the results into the existing `"items"` array of the basket we use the same field name in argument to `"as"`.

In this form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) you typically still want "related" documents even though it gives you the control to do whatever you want. In this case we can compare the array content from `"items"` in the parent document which we set as a variable for the pipeline to use with the array under `"flavours"` in the foreign collection. A logical comparison for the two "sets" of values here where they "intersect" is using the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) operator using the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) so we can compare on a "logical operation".

The main work here is being done in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) which is simply using `$map` on the array from the `"flavours"` array of the foreign document, processed with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in comparison to the `"items"` we passed into the pipeline and essentially re-written in order to "merge" the matched content.

The [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) reduces down the list for consideration to only those which match something present within the `"items"`, and then we can use [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in order to extract the detail from the `"items"` and merge it with each remaining `"flavours"` entry which matches using the [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) operator. Noting here that we also take some "parent" detail from the "shirt" as the `"name"` and `"price"` fields which are common to the variations in size and color.

Since this is still an "array" within the matched document(s) to the join condition, in order to get a "flat list" of objects suitable for "merged" entries in the resulting `"items"` of the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) we simply apply [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), which within the context of matched items left only creates "little" overhead, and [`$replaceRoot`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) in order to promote the content under that key to the top level.

The result is just the "merged" content listed in the `"items"` of the basket.

#### Sub-optimal MongoDB

The alternate approaches are really not that great since all involve returning other "flavours" which do not actually match the items in the basket. This basically involves "post-filtering" the results obtained from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) as opposed to "pre-filtering" which the process above does.

So the next case here would be using methods to manipulate the returned array in order to remove the items which don't actually match:

```
// Using legacy $lookup
let alternate = await Basket.aggregate([
  { "$match": { _id, basketName } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Shirt.collection.name,
    "localField": "items.itemFlavId",
    "foreignField": "flavours.flavId",
    "as": "ordered_items"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "items": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "ordered_items": {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": "$ordered_items",
                  "as": "o",
                  "in": {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": {
                        "$filter": {
                          "input": "$$o.flavours",
                          "cond": {
                            "$in": ["$$this.flavId", "$items.itemFlavId"]
                          }
                        }
                      },
                      "as": "f",
                      "in": {
                        "$mergeObjects": [
                          { "name": "$$o.name", "price": "$$o.price" },
                          "$$f"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "initialValue": [],
              "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$items",
            "in": {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$this",
                { "$arrayElemAt": [
                  "$$ordered_items",
                  { "$indexOfArray": [
                    "$$ordered_items.flavId", "$$this.itemFlavId"
                  ]}
                ]}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ordered_items": "$$REMOVE"
  }}
]);
```

Here I'm still using some MongoDB 3.6 features, but these are not a "requirement" of the logic involved. The main constraint in this approach is actually the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) which requires MongoDB 3.4 or greater.

Using the same "legacy" form of `$lookup` as you were attempting, we still get the desired results as you display but that of course contains information in the `"flavours"` that does not match the `"items"` in the basket. In much the same way as shown in the previous listing we can apply [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) here to remove the items which don't match. The same process here uses that [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) output as the input for [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), which again is doing the same "merge" process as before.

Where the [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) comes in is because the resulting processing where there is an "array" target from [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with documents that themselves contain an `"array"` of `"flavours"` is that these arrays need to be "merged" into a single array for further processing. The `$reduce` simply uses the processed output and performs a [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) on each of the "inner" arrays returned to make these results singular. We already "merged" the content, so this becomes the new "merged" `"items"`.

#### Older Still $unwind

And of course the final way to present ( even though there are other combinations ) is using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the arrays and using [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to put it back together:

```
let old = await Basket.aggregate([
  { "$match": { _id, basketName } },
  { "$unwind": "$items" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Shirt.collection.name,
    "localField": "items.itemFlavId",
    "foreignField": "flavours.flavId",
    "as": "ordered_items"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$ordered_items" },
  { "$unwind": "$ordered_items.flavours" },
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$eq": [
          "$items.itemFlavId",
          "$ordered_items.flavours.flavId"
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "basketName": { "$first": "$basketName" },
    "items": {
      "$push": {
        "dateAdded": "$items.dateAdded",
        "itemFlavId": "$items.itemFlavId",
        "name": "$ordered_items.name",
        "price": "$ordered_items.price",
        "flavId": "$ordered_items.flavours.flavId",
        "size": "$ordered_items.flavours.size",
        "color": "$ordered_items.flavours.color"
      }
    }
  }}
]);
```

Most of this should be pretty self explanatory as [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is simply a tool to "flatten" array content into singular document entries. In order to just get the results we want we can use [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) to compare the two fields. Using MongoDB 3.6 you "could" use [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) within a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) here:

```
{ "$match": {
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      "$items.itemFlavId",
      "$ordered_items.flavours.flavId"
    ]
  }
}}
```

But when it comes down to it, if you have MongoDB 3.6 with it's other features then [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is the wrong thing to do here due to all the overhead it will actually add.

So all that really happens is you [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) then "flatten" the documents and finally [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) all related detail together using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) to recreate the `"items"` in the basket. It "looks simple" and is probably the most easy form to understand, however "simplicity" does not equal "performance" and this would be pretty brutal to use in a real world use case.

### Summary

That should cover the explanation of the things you need to do when working with "joins" that are going to compare items within arrays. This probably should lead you on the path of realizing this is not really a great idea and it would be far better to keep your "skus" listed "separately" rather than listing them all related under a single "item".

It also should in part be a lesson that "joins" in general are not a great idea with MongoDB. You really only should define such relations where they are "absolutely necessary". In such a case of "details for items in a basket", then contrary to traditional RDBMS patterns it would actually be far better in terms of performance to simply "embed" that detail from the start. In that way you don't need complicated join conditions just to get a result, which might have saved *"a few bytes"* in storage but is taking a lot more time than what should have been a simple request for the basket with all the detail already "embedded". That really should be the primary reason why you are using something like MongoDB in the first place.

So if you have to do it, then really you should be sticking with the first form since where you have the available features to use then use them best to their advantage. Whilst other approaches may seem easier, it won't help the application performance, and of course best performance would be embedding to begin with.

---

A full listing follows for demonstration of the above discussed methods and for basic comparison to prove that the provided data does in fact "join" as long as the other parts of the application set-up are working as they should be. So a model on "how it should be done" in addition to demonstrating the full concepts.

```
const { Schema, Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/basket';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug', true);


const basketItemSchema = new Schema({
  dateAdded: { type: Number, default: Date.now() },
  itemFlavId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId }
},{ _id: false });

const basketSchema = new Schema({
  basketName: String,
  items: [basketItemSchema]
});

const flavourSchema = new Schema({
  flavId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
  size: String,
  color: String
},{ _id: false });

const shirtSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  price: Number,
  flavours: [flavourSchema]
});

const Basket = mongoose.model('Basket', basketSchema);
const Shirt = mongoose.model('Shirt', shirtSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    // clean data
    await Promise.all(Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.remove()));

    // set up data for test
    await Basket.create({
      _id: ObjectId("5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc"),
      basketName: "Default",
      items: [
        {
          dateAdded: 1526996879787.0,
          itemFlavId: ObjectId("5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3")
        }
      ]
    });

    await Shirt.create({
      _id: ObjectId("5a797ef0768d8418866eb0f6"),
      name: "Supermanshirt",
      price: 9.99,
      flavours: [
        {
          flavId: ObjectId("5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3"),
          size: "M",
          color: "white"
        },
        {
          flavId: ObjectId("3a797f8c768d8418866eb0f7"),
          size: "XL",
          color: "red"
        }
      ]
    });

    // Store some vars like you have
    let _id = ObjectId("5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc"),
        basketName = "Default";

    // Run non-correlated $lookup
    let optimal = await Basket.aggregate([
      { "$match": { _id, basketName } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Shirt.collection.name,
        "as": "items",
        "let": { "items": "$items" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$setIsSubset": ["$$items.itemflavId", "$flavours.flavId"]
            }
          }},
          { "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "items": {
              "$map": {
                "input": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$flavours",
                    "cond": { "$in": [ "$$this.flavId", "$$items.itemFlavId" ]}
                  }
                },
                "in": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    { "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$$items",
                      { "$indexOfArray": [
                        "$$items.itemFlavId", "$$this.flavId" ] }
                    ]},
                    { "name": "$name", "price": "$price" },
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }},
          { "$unwind": "$items" },
          { "$replaceRoot": {  "newRoot": "$items" } }
        ]
      }}
    ])

    log(optimal);

    // Using legacy $lookup
    let alternate = await Basket.aggregate([
      { "$match": { _id, basketName } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Shirt.collection.name,
        "localField": "items.itemFlavId",
        "foreignField": "flavours.flavId",
        "as": "ordered_items"
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "items": {
          "$let": {
            "vars": {
              "ordered_items": {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": {
                    "$map": {
                      "input": "$ordered_items",
                      "as": "o",
                      "in": {
                        "$map": {
                          "input": {
                            "$filter": {
                              "input": "$$o.flavours",
                              "cond": {
                                "$in": ["$$this.flavId", "$items.itemFlavId"]
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          "as": "f",
                          "in": {
                            "$mergeObjects": [
                              { "name": "$$o.name", "price": "$$o.price" },
                              "$$f"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "initialValue": [],
                  "in": { "$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
              }
            },
            "in": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$items",
                "in": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$this",
                    { "$arrayElemAt": [
                      "$$ordered_items",
                      { "$indexOfArray": [
                        "$$ordered_items.flavId", "$$this.itemFlavId"
                      ]}
                    ]}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "ordered_items": "$$REMOVE"
      }}
    ]);
    log(alternate);

    // Or really old style

    let old = await Basket.aggregate([
      { "$match": { _id, basketName } },
      { "$unwind": "$items" },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Shirt.collection.name,
        "localField": "items.itemFlavId",
        "foreignField": "flavours.flavId",
        "as": "ordered_items"
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$ordered_items" },
      { "$unwind": "$ordered_items.flavours" },
      { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              "$items.itemFlavId",
              "$ordered_items.flavours.flavId"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$$KEEP",
          "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "basketName": { "$first": "$basketName" },
        "items": {
          "$push": {
            "dateAdded": "$items.dateAdded",
            "itemFlavId": "$items.itemFlavId",
            "name": "$ordered_items.name",
            "price": "$ordered_items.price",
            "flavId": "$ordered_items.flavours.flavId",
            "size": "$ordered_items.flavours.size",
            "color": "$ordered_items.flavours.color"
          }
        }
      }}
    ]);

    log(old);


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }

})()
```

And sample output as:

```
Mongoose: baskets.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: shirts.remove({}, {})
Mongoose: baskets.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc"), basketName: 'Default', items: [ { dateAdded: 1526996879787, itemFlavId: ObjectId("5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3") } ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: shirts.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a797ef0768d8418866eb0f6"), name: 'Supermanshirt', price: 9.99, flavours: [ { flavId: ObjectId("5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3"), size: 'M', color: 'white' }, { flavId: ObjectId("3a797f8c768d8418866eb0f7"), size: 'XL', color: 'red' } ], __v: 0 })
Mongoose: baskets.aggregate([ { '$match': { _id: 5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc, basketName: 'Default' } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'shirts', as: 'items', let: { items: '$items' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$setIsSubset': [ '$$items.itemflavId', '$flavours.flavId' ] } } }, { '$project': { _id: 0, items: { '$map': { input: { '$filter': { input: '$flavours', cond: { '$in': [Array] } } }, in: { '$mergeObjects': [ { '$arrayElemAt': [Array] }, { name: '$name', price: '$price' }, '$$this' ] } } } } }, { '$unwind': '$items' }, { '$replaceRoot': { newRoot: '$items' } } ] } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc",
    "basketName": "Default",
    "items": [
      {
        "dateAdded": 1526996879787,
        "itemFlavId": "5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3",
        "name": "Supermanshirt",
        "price": 9.99,
        "flavId": "5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3",
        "size": "M",
        "color": "white"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
Mongoose: baskets.aggregate([ { '$match': { _id: 5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc, basketName: 'Default' } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'shirts', localField: 'items.itemFlavId', foreignField: 'flavours.flavId', as: 'ordered_items' } }, { '$addFields': { items: { '$let': { vars: { ordered_items: { '$reduce': { input: { '$map': { input: '$ordered_items', as: 'o', in: { '$map': [Object] } } }, initialValue: [], in: { '$concatArrays': [ '$$value', '$$this' ] } } } }, in: { '$map': { input: '$items', in: { '$mergeObjects': [ '$$this', { '$arrayElemAt': [ '$$ordered_items', [Object] ] } ] } } } } }, ordered_items: '$$REMOVE' } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc",
    "basketName": "Default",
    "items": [
      {
        "dateAdded": 1526996879787,
        "itemFlavId": "5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3",
        "name": "Supermanshirt",
        "price": 9.99,
        "flavId": "5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3",
        "size": "M",
        "color": "white"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
Mongoose: baskets.aggregate([ { '$match': { _id: 5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc, basketName: 'Default' } }, { '$unwind': '$items' }, { '$lookup': { from: 'shirts', localField: 'items.itemFlavId', foreignField: 'flavours.flavId', as: 'ordered_items' } }, { '$unwind': '$ordered_items' }, { '$unwind': '$ordered_items.flavours' }, { '$redact': { '$cond': { if: { '$eq': [ '$items.itemFlavId', '$ordered_items.flavours.flavId' ] }, then: '$$KEEP', else: '$$PRUNE' } } }, { '$group': { _id: '$_id', basketName: { '$first': '$basketName' }, items: { '$push': { dateAdded: '$items.dateAdded', itemFlavId: '$items.itemFlavId', name: '$ordered_items.name', price: '$ordered_items.price', flavId: '$ordered_items.flavours.flavId', size: '$ordered_items.flavours.size', color: '$ordered_items.flavours.color' } } } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5a797ef0333d8418866ebabc",
    "basketName": "Default",
    "items": [
      {
        "dateAdded": 1526996879787,
        "itemFlavId": "5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3",
        "name": "Supermanshirt",
        "price": 9.99,
        "flavId": "5a797f8c768d8418866ebad3",
        "size": "M",
        "color": "white"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! exactly solved my problem and after 2 days of studying i think i understood most parts of it. I could migrate it to my productive solution and it works! Thanks again.